# Outlook Interop GetTable operation fails randomly

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I use this code to find emails in outlook

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlook;
outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder folder = outlook
    .GetNamespace("MAPI")
    .Folders
    .OfType<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder>()
    .Skip(1)
    .First()
    .Folders
    .OfType<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder>()
    .Skip(1)
    .First()
    .Folders
    .OfType<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder>()
    .First();
        
string query = @"@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription"" like '%3Z70699Y0404605413%'";

var table = folder.GetTable(query); // operation fails sometimes
```

it works, but randomly it does not work. The `GetTable` sometimes gives error like *operation failed* (the exact phrasing is "Operace se nezdařila"). There are no further details in the exception. It seems to get worse over time, when *sometimes* gradually changes to *always*. My suspicion is it may have something to do with leaking com objects when using linq. But honestly do not know. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty weird looking code when it comes to the Outlook Object Model - never hardcode folder indices, even names are a bad practice. The order is never guaranteed and the names can be localized.

Are you sure you even end up with the right folder? Does folder.Name return the expected value?

Comment: I tried to simplify the code as much as possible. It returns the right folder even when the error occurs though. It is folder with custom name so I am pretty sure it is the right one.